# Quickly search class members (const ints, const string etc)

Tags: c#, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class that defines constants for my design. For example the following :

```
public static class ObjectTypes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier for the ConfigurableObjectType ObjectType.
    /// </summary>
    public const uint ConfigurableObjectType = 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier for the FunctionalGroupType ObjectType.
    /// </summary>
    public const uint FunctionalGroupType = 4;

    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier for the ProtocolType ObjectType.
    /// </summary>
    public const uint ProtocolType = 5;
}
```

Now in my code I have calculated and integer value for.eg valueInt and I would like to compare valueInt with all the constants defined in this class. Is there a quick way to do it without using If-then-else blocks or switch case because in case there are a large number of constants this kind of an approach will result in a large code. Is a better approach somehow possible? I am working in C#.

Note : I cannot change the design for the above mentioned class as I get such a class predefined for e.g from a library or a class designed by someone else which I cannot change but I should only refer to in my code.

Comment: Removing `[C++]` and `[Java]` as these don't appear to be related. I don't see how this is object orientated.

Comment: Maybe you should be using `enum`s, where you could have, e.g. `(ObjectTypes)5` is the same as `ObjectTypes.ProtocolType`. And for the strings, `Enum.Parse`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I presumed because it is a general question, I am right now working with C#, however I would like to know the approach for Java or C++ too as it makes it an interesting question for me with regards to Java and C++ too, and sorry but could you please explain why don't you feel it is related to object-orientation?

Comment: @TimS. Yes I definitely could have but such classes come directly from certain standardised classes which have not been coded by me, for e.g in case of library classes or similar

Comment: @Ricky Asking a question for multiple languages usually get downvoted heavily so I was trying to save you a few downvotes.  How it is done in each language is completely different.

Comment: @TimS. Thanks for the pointers, I would keep this in mind the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use reflection. Should test to make sure it doesn't perform unacceptably for you though.

```
    private static bool IsDefined(uint i) {
        var constants = typeof(ObjectTypes).GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral).ToArray();

        foreach(var constant in constants) {
            if(i == (uint)constant.GetRawConstantValue()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did need something similar.

Comment: Thank you..I learnt something new today thanks to you and Marvin who also provided a similar answer. It worked like a charm, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Although not a pretty construct, to give a possible solution for the given problem without changing existing code.

The following code uses reflection to compare

```
        string fieldName = "not found";
        uint testValue = 5;

        Type t = typeof(ObjectTypes);
        FieldInfo[] f = t.GetFields();
        Array.ForEach<FieldInfo>(f, (info) => { if (testValue == (uint)info.GetValue(null)) fieldName = info.Name; });
```

and yields "ProtocolType" at the end of the code.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks interesting, I would definitely try this and post here soon!